# import jquery from npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have installed jquery throught npm.

package.json:

```
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
```

In my JS I do:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

However it still says that $ is undefined in my browser why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that it doesn't has a `default` export syntax, but you have used the `default` import.

Try the following syntax:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: Well its not working for me, do you mean to add the syntax at the top of your js file

Comment: * is not defined, now i have loaded jquery through cdn and its working for the time being but I think by reading the npm document for jquery I kinda find the solution to use it through npm node module. However if you have quick fix you can tell

Comment: I need to see the configuration of your proj :]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you might want to check out Webpack's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery).